# Spark scala error handling

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scripting

Am converting scripts from Teradata BTEQ to SPARK using Scala. Am wondering how to handle scenarios in BTEQ as below:

```
.IF ERRORCODE > 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE
```

Say if i have an exception while making a join between the hive tables and assigning it to a data frame. Or when i have an exception when i perform a save overwrite,

```
sqlJoinDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable
```

How can i return an exception and exit or perform another function ?

Since `Try`, `Catch` will not work here and exception will occur only when the action is executed and we will not be able to find out on which stage of transformation the issue had first occurred.

Comment: I have say that - control flow with exceptions + SQL + large scale data - feels so wrong. And even if you fine with that, it should never get nearby `SaveMode.Overwrite`

Comment: So can you let me know, on how to proceed with this scenario.

Comment: IMHO This is complex architecture question (there is much more to it, than simple how to throw an exception), not something that can be _properly_ answered in SO format.

Comment: Any excerpt or material might be of great help to me.

Comment: Short - write data to a temporary storage, validate on the way (with separate scan or customized accumulator), if validations succeeds, overwrite the existing data, if not delete temporary and fail the job.